# How to limit by column repetitions in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I want to select only rows that contain fewer than 3 total repetitions of an element in a column.  To be specific, I have a large directory of phone numbers, names, and cities.  I want to export a list of only "small cities," such that any line with a city that has fewer than three entries across the document is kept.  So, for example

```
Name, City, State
Foo, L.A., CA
Bar, L.A., CA
Sam, L.A., CA
Tricia, Kent, WA
Bob, Kent, WA
Ida, Boo, PA
Monster Mash, Whack, PA
Zoomacroom, L.A., CA
Otter Pop, Boo, PA
Snake, HP, WA
Ronnie the Bear, Boo, PA
```

Should become:

```
Name, City, State
Tricia, Kent, WA
Bob, Kent, WA
Snake, HP, WA
Monster Mash, Whack, PA
```

I also don't have to use pandas - I can use csv just as easily; I just happen to already have it imported in my cleaning script.

Comment: Ah, I see my confusion: you say both "fewer than 4 total repetitions" and "fewer than three individuals".

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing.  Now it should match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
>>> small_cities = df.groupby(["City", "State"]).filter(lambda x: x.count() < 3)
>>> small_cities
           Name   City State
3        Tricia   Kent    WA
4           Bob   Kent    WA
6  Monster Mash  Whack    PA
9         Snake     HP    WA

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: I **think** the OP changed the desired DataFrame in the first 5 minutes of posting. This answer describes how to remove repetitions in all columns (not just for this specific example of Cities/States where that doesn't make a whole lot of sense).*

You can do this for a single column (remove City names seen more than 3 times):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('City')

In [12]: g.filter(lambda x: len(x['City']) < 4)
Out[12]: 
               Name   City State
5               Ida    Boo    PA
8         Otter Pop    Boo    PA
10  Ronnie the Bear    Boo    PA
9             Snake     HP    WA
3            Tricia   Kent    WA
4               Bob   Kent    WA
6      Monster Mash  Whack    PA
```

To do it in all columns (this is a little messy! However, you could make a function to do this for arbitrary frames...):

```
In [13]: less_than_4 = ((df.groupby('City').City.transform(lambda x: len(x) < 4))
                      & (df.groupby('State').State.transform(lambda x: len(x) < 4))
                      & ((df.groupby('Name').Name.transform(lambda x: len(x) < 4))))

In [14]: df[less_than_4]
Out[14]: 
     Name  City State
3  Tricia  Kent    WA
4     Bob  Kent    WA
9   Snake    HP    WA
```

And slightly more elegantly:

```
from operator import and_
df[reduce(and_, (df.groupby(col)[col].transform(lambda x: len(x) < 4)
                      for col in df.columns))]
```

Comment: I think grouping only by `City` is dangerous-- there's a Kent, OH, for example.

Comment: @DSM That's true in this example, I guess more generally for limiting reps in columns this is what you'd do (but in this context, you're right it doesn't make sense!)...

Comment: @DSM also, I think this example was changed in the first 5 minutes... Bit confused now it's different to OPs desired output!

Comment: The first would match if you used < 3 instead of < 4.  I don't quite follow what your second example is doing.

Comment: @DSM it's removing all repetition of <4 in _any_ column (and and-ing together), so PA is removed as it's seen 4 times in df.

Comment: Oh, so the goal of the original version was to remove rows in which any individual value occurs 4 or more times in a column.  I get you.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
for line in set(content):
    if content.count([-2:]) < 4:
        output.append(line[-2:])
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#df is the pandas DataFrame holding your data
df.groupby(["City","State"]).filter(lambda x: len(x)<3)
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()